# Msgbus - Subscribing material data-block in material slot

Tags: python

I'm trying to subscribe the material data-block in a material slot using msgbus. I've written following code, but it seems the callback can't be triggered for some reason.

```
import bpy

owner = object()

subscribe_to = (bpy.types.MaterialSlot, "material")


def msgbus_callback(context):
    print("Material change")
    
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=owner,
    args=(bpy.context,),
    notify=msgbus_callback,
)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `subscribe_to = (bpy.types.Object, "active_material_index")` but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. The messagebus works with the properties of a datablock, not with the datablock itself. see [https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bpy.msgbus.html?highlight=subscribe_to#limitations]